# Node.JS: debug to know one object's prototype name

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, socket.io

I am reading [the code](https://github.com/guille/chat-example) of a [chat project](http://socket.io/) as a demo for socket.io

In index.js, here is a snippet:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

So I use Node.JS debugger:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

// add:
debugger;
watch("io");
```

The command is:

```
node debug index.js
```

It stops at var io = ...
But I don't know how to get the information of the object "io".
Actually when I type io in the terminal, it says:
io is not defined.

if I type http, it will output the definition of http.

If I type app, it says: app is not defined.

I am confused.
How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just type 'repl' in 'debug >' prompt and then you can type and get all variables values

Comment: I did this way. When I type io after the prompt >, nothing happened except a new line with the prompt > begins.

Comment: because after running 'debug' command debugger stops on first line. You need to type 'next' in debug prompt a few ones for arriving to 6th string in your code. Then type 'repl' and 'io'

Comment: Thank you. It works! Just one question: if I want to know the variable, I have to use 'repl' first, right? However, I find a strange phenomenon: I can get the definition of http (in a different way, much less detailed). How is it this way?

Comment: I think it's not strange :)

Comment: Sorry I did not specify my question correctly. (a) If I only use "debug" without "repl", I cannot get the definition of the variable "app" and "io", only of the variable "http". (b) Even thought I can get the definition of variable "http" using "debug" without "repl", its definition is less detailed than in the case of using "repl". By "strange", I mean I should've not got the definition of the var "http" in the case of using "debug" without "repl".

Answer (score 0):

I use node inspector. It works like a charm.